# react function error while returning true

Tags: return

i created two functions to check if a value is in an array
if yes then just console log...
otherwise add the value to the array
but when i return true from the inner function i got undefined in parent function.
code is here

```
 checkInclude = (array, value) => {
    if (array.length) {
      array.find(item => {
        if (item.name == value) {
          return true;
        }
      });
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
  chipClick = event => {
    let wholeArray = this.props.chips;
    let items = this.state.selectedItems;
    const result = this.checkInclude(items, event.target.id);
    console.log(result);
    if (!result) {
      wholeArray.filter(item => {
        if (item.name === event.target.id) {
          items.push(item);
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log("got a match");
    }
    this.setState({ selectedItems: items, found: false });

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do not `return true`

```
checkInclude = (array, value) => {
    if (array.length) {
      return array.find(item => { // you need to add return
        if (item.name == value) {
          return true;
        }
      }) !== undefined;
          // find() returns element of array,
          // so you need to cast it to boolean
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

`checkInclude` is returning nothing when `array.length !=0`, check @x00 answer to correct this. Regardless this, you should possibly use `some` method of array instead of `checkInclude`

```
chipClick = event => {
    let wholeArray = this.props.chips;
    let items = this.state.selectedItems;
    const result = items.some(item=> item.name == event.target.id);
    console.log(result);
    if (!result) {
      wholeArray.filter(item => {
        if (item.name === event.target.id) {
          items.push(item);
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log("got a match");
    }
    this.setState({ selectedItems: items, found: false });

};
```